# WebView - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

Estou criando a seguinte tela no [android](/questions/tagged/android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activities_fundo_cinza"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Webview
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Mas estou com o seguinte erro:

> 04-07 14:55:45.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1693): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Webview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.test.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/br.livetouch.synchro-2, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa reescrever **Webview** para **WebView**. Assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activities_fundo_cinza"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

O nome da tag é utilizada para carregar a classe por isso tem que ser **exatamente** o mesmo nome.

Como descrito na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

> Em geral, no vocabulário `XML` para declarar elementos da interface segue a estrutura e a convenção de nomes das classes e métodos, onde os elementos e o nome do elemento corresponde a classe e os atributos correspondem aos métodos. Na verdade, a correspondência é tão direta que você pode supor qual atributo `XML` corresponde a qual método de classe, ou supor qual classe corresponde a qual a um elemento `XML`. Entretanto, note que nem todo vocabulário é idêntico. Em alguns casos existe uma leve diferença de nomeação. Por exemplo, o elemento `EditText` tem um atributo text que corresponde a `EditText.setText()`